# C# - Process with an id of "xxxxxx" is not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process

I have a windows form and I make the following call to open chrome up with a URL:

```
 string uri = Uri.EscapeUriString(URL.ToString());
 Process process = Process.Start("chrome", uri + " --new-window");
 return process.Id;
```

The problem is that I get the error: "Process with an id of "xxxxxxx" is not running" when I call the following:

```
procsChrome = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
```

The processID is the one returned in the previous code snippet. Now, this WORKS when I have NO CHROME WINDOW OPEN.

But if I have another chrome window open, I get this error. I monitored the processes in Task Manager and when no chrome is open, a new process with the the process id returned from the code snippet 1 is created.

When one or more chrome windows are already open, I get a process id from code snippet 1, but the newly opened chrome window is running under some other id. Why is this happening?

Edit 2:

Here is the method I get the error on. The parameter `int processID` is the process.Id returned above from code snippet 1.

```
 public static string GetCodeFromURL(int processID)
    {
        Process procsChrome = null;
        try
        {
            if (processID == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-1 returned as ID");
                return null;
            }
            procsChrome = Process.GetProcessById(processID); //I GET ERROR HERE
            // the chrome process must have a window 
            if (procsChrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                MessageBox.Show("Process failed");

            // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
            AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(procsChrome.MainWindowHandle);
            var SearchBar = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
            if (SearchBar != null)
            {
                bool noCode = false;
                while (noCode == false)
                {
                    string fullURL = (string)SearchBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);
                    if (!(fullURL.Contains("code") && fullURL.Contains("state")))
                    {
                        if (procsChrome.HasExited)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Process failed. User closed browser.");
                            procsChrome.Close();
                            noCode = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string stateToken = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fullURL.Substring(new[] { 0, fullURL.IndexOf('?') }.Max())).Get("state");
                        if (stateToken.Equals("296bc9a0-a2a2-4a57-be1a-d0e2fd9bb601"))
                        {
                            noCode = true;
                            string code = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fullURL.Substring(new[] { 0, fullURL.IndexOf('?') }.Max())).Get("code");
                            procsChrome.CloseMainWindow();
                            procsChrome.Close();
                            return code;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occured on getting the URL. Please try again. The exception is: " + exception.ToString());
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. But most likely, the first process you start, when Chrome is already running, delegates handling of the URL to the already-existing Chrome process and then immediately exits. So the ID is no longer valid when you try to get the process later. How best to deal with that depends on why you want the process in the first place. Again, your question lacks those details as well.

Comment: I am trying to authenticate a user using 2 Factor. The authentication "push" takes place via a browser window. I build a URL and open it inside a new browser window (first code snippet). Then, I have a method that monitors changes in the browser URL. If the user clicks the "push" button, the browser URL changes, and a code appears.  I use that code for authentication automatically and the chrome window closes. Now, to get that browser URL, I get the process id of that browser. Problem is, that I am not getting that process id if I have one or more additional chrome windows open.

Comment: I also edited my question to provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: @Raza156 chrome actually uses separate processes for each opened tab, and 1 main process. They all are called "chrome.exe". (Dumb, i know, classic Google). This can possibly be the issue. You are taking the wrong process

Comment: How can I get the correct process then? Can you please guide me?

Comment: @Raza156 i think that chrome is opening a new window and then closing a process which was used to open that window. Getting PID of exactly the tab you opened is not an easy task. I am not quite sure how to do that. It would help if you could explain why exactly do you need the chrome process after you called it. Maybe we can find a workaround

Comment: Hi, please check my second comment on above to see why I require exactly that process's id.
Basically, when I start the process (code snippet 1 in my post), I return that process's id in that method. 

Then I call another method that takes that process id as a parameter, and then loops through that process's URL (in this case, the chrome browser's URL) to get a specific parameter. Once I get that parameters value, I can use it to authenticate the user. It is unique each time.

I updated my post with the code and where I get the error.

Comment: @Raza156 This is really not the way of doing this. I don't even think you can do it the way you are trying to.You should instead setup an Http listener in your app that listens for connections on your web server. Once user opens your webpage, it sends a request to your app with your unique ID which you can use to authenticate your user

Comment: @Raza156 Also, what if your user is not using Chrome? What if it is a different browser? You should open your URLs in a different way, using their default browser, not by launching Chrome directly from code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome seems to behave in this way by default, creating anothing process and closing the original one, which means you end up with an incorrect Process ID. And when you have multiple Chrome processes with the same website/title you end up having no control over it.

As some suggested using the parameter "--incognito" will solve it, whoever this would also create other unwanted behavioural issues.

I've looked at the Chrome parameters list and tried a few, using the parameter **"--no-service-autorun"** seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why chrome is behaving like that. Can you try to have your code launch chrome in incognito mode?

Using the test code below i was able to launch 2 distinct incognito processes each with their own process id. Note: these launched in the same browser window as 2 tabs.

I think using `--incognito` will get you out of trouble.

```cs
  public class LaunchChromeProof
  {
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public LaunchChromeProof(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
      _output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CanLaunchChromeIcognito_AndFetchProcesses_ByID()
    {
      var chromePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
      var chromeProcess = Process.Start(chromePath, "www.google.com --incognito");
      Assert.NotEqual(0, chromeProcess.Id);


      //launch a second session
      var chrome2ndProcess = Process.Start(chromePath, "www.google.com --incognito");
      Assert.NotEqual(0, chrome2ndProcess.Id);

      _output.WriteLine($"Session 1 ProcessID: {chromeProcess.Id}");
      _output.WriteLine($"Session 2 ProcessID: {chrome2ndProcess.Id}");



      //check we can fetch the correct process by the process id for each session
      var fetchProcess1 = Process.GetProcessById(chromeProcess.Id);
      Assert.Equal(chromeProcess.Id, fetchProcess1.Id);

      var fetchProcess2 = Process.GetProcessById(chrome2ndProcess.Id);
      Assert.Equal(chrome2ndProcess.Id, fetchProcess2.Id);

      _output.WriteLine($"Fetched Session 1 Process: {fetchProcess1.Id}");
      _output.WriteLine($"Fetched Session 2 Process: {fetchProcess2.Id}");
    }
```

[image: test results]

Comment: also i was able to use `Process.GetProcessById(chromeProcess.Id)` and `Process.GetProcessById(chrome2ndProcess.Id)` each returning the correct process IDs as i would expect

Comment: Hi. Just tried that. When another non incognito window is open, I get the same error. It opens up under a different id than the one it was started with.

Comment: You may have to look at what you code does after you return the process ID. According to the quick proofs i wrote it is possible to get the correct process by it's id.

Comment: Perhaps try to run the `xunit` tests as is with out your code to see it working, then go from there.

Comment: I just added the method where the process id gets used. After I return the processId, that's when it gets used. So if method A returns process id. Method B takes it as a paraemeter.

int x = Method A();
string c = Method(x);